# Plotting data on x axis in Highstock

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

I am currently trying to plot some data which I receive via a `HTTP` request. The issue that I am having is that `the x-axis doesn't plot the timestamp correctly because it it's in Unix format`. I've read some other similar question on SO such as: [Example One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842176/rendering-highcharts-datatimes-on-the-x-axis-at-regular-intervals)

The issue is that I'm not passing an object but directly an `Unix time data`. When hovering the graph, you can see that the `x-axis` doesn't display the date and hour correctly.

**Here is a fiddle with my current graph: [Graph Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ZombieChowder/obyjq19c/5/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you actually have `datetime` values, showing them using `category` is sort of a hack, and would also not show gaps between points correctly if they are not evenly spaced.

Instead you could merge your two arrays into pairs and then supply it to the series as proper X-Y values for a `datetime` axis. You also have to multiply your `datetime` values by 1000 to get milliseconds, which Highcharts expects.

For example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/obyjq19c/12/)), merging:

```
dataArray.push(selectedData);
timeDataArray.push(selectedTime);

var mergedArray = timeDataArray.map(function(e, i) {
    return [e*1000, dataArray[i]];
});
```

And axis and series:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},
series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: mergedArray
}]
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that I have to multiply it by a `1000` but I wasn't sure how to do it.